# Why am I getting UnknownHostException using HtmlUnitDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am writing a test that should get only the URL from the redirect, there is no need to load the non-existing page. Every time I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (bank.test.com)
```

How I said, there is no need to load only what I need is to get the URL when a user submits the form, how should I do it?

This is the code where it is causing exception:

```java
@Step("Sign in")
    public static String signIn(WebDriver driver, String url, String username, String password) {
        driver.get(url);

        HtmlUnitDriverSteps.setFieldValueByName(driver, USERNAME, username);
        HtmlUnitDriverSteps.setFieldValueByName(driver, PASSWORD, password + Keys.ENTER);
        
        return driver.getCurrentUrl();
    }
```

Is there solution for my issue?

Comment: Regarding your main question - to answer we need more info about your case and the flow you like to test. I guess you call this with the url of the login page. But i have no idea where you think the redirect takes place - when retrieving the login page or when submitting your credentials.

Comment: When the page is loaded, the user fills in the two inputs (username, password) data, when the user clicks on the sign-in button, the backend should redirect the user to a page that contains 6 digits code that is used to generate an access token. But issue is problem when the endpoint ends with callback, I tried to change to for example oauth-login

Comment: OAuth is currently not supported by HtmlUnit - you have to use a real browser driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the partial *url_string* *`bank.test.com`* you need to pass the complete (fully qualified) *url_string* as follows:

```
https://bank.test.com
```

Comment: Strange, because that is what I have in my property: ```redirect=https://bank.test.com/account/callback ```

Comment: @Sanady_ Edit that and let  me know the status.

Comment: It is edited, a few minutes ago

Comment: @Sanady_ I still doubt, it seems to be a _`callback`_ end point **not** the intended url.

Comment: Well yes, but all I need is that URL which is containing the code. When the user sign-in it gets code attached at the end of the endpoint. But the HtmlUnitDriver instead of giving me only the URL I get that exception

Comment: It is fixed, the issue was that I was calling callback how undetected Selenium said... Thank you for replay

Answer (score 0):

> UnknownHostException: No such host is known

This usually point to some problems resolving the URL into an ip address to connect to.
Please check if this url is available from your browser. Maybe there is a proxy configured for your browser.

Comment: The catch is that I don't need any of that, I mean converting domain to IP address. Only what I need is the code that is attached to that non-existing URL

Comment: Sorry but there is no way to contact a server without having the ip address. Maybe you have to learn a bit more about how the internet works.